# How to fs.writefile text with property key

Tags: javascript, node.js, writefile

I have text i want to save in a .json file with a property key. I want the text to be saved into the property key to be read in another file. How would i save this text in the property key.

Text:
pozBpk8zf06uxvZmseZo-E99TgYOYH87FUZeCDyZmqnJOHb9u0ovW8gN1hYBFCc4MSw1Ne9FETFn112XWptkyV3stDIwaanLdP8SbrdrrPclWhWZKMeDb8DGzzM=oAwxro2UFmaWdCB0jexR5qgpszRWo7DstAFtTNyv4h5rFxIrSBBI8ukwkbxgk1C3w=WtvZ3EXYJwxEcbcyaEPtkfU0nO2ZyzbEtS7WtgSYPUUd6_=Pjea0bwSxEEY4sCoU5IEiqgKdziTE0StGkS7UD3PLJk9AasZiJJLECMh5f9ZNrGfEj-pTvcB=Vfx6jNUwD6g03gwJwn2KPR9M5gTnMF3UnKlevoEoKf6j=8Yt63CS498RHnu0Yf3jePokFZOYb6YJB=EEEJwE0Rfoab5LyvYvF9rJSJagw1whrPep966Zyzw0NOh4NG55Zo3A=2ZB0jYd5AcWgEvsUh=e4zG1GJZnNpF-6PW4_WVEoblmX4T17PPgkhPjcK919a46nOlTiz-Ol-2gGRYXbV3Z8vjuOHq=MWp-a0F0v3LnouPEWykv1oWcb0peBCJ=54Hlv2--DMp72vY-bYtF8BEuZLcyaGXpo_VhviCoZkB3GcZjerDw47by7=FJ8xsEkeL7z9c1YF79=TAP1uqkTOFIk59mq-L7nyn=tXhx9B3etxatgCBGzsHJVc52B0uq0BKJeUzB7IAex-HpE-GS31=zujnpwR75gu7sjKDmVBoi2RgGqMrBSPgyhCXcZVMFGcdt_riDcbGKF-hgITAGhdZacpZGfVdF-sSCX4HEV2C3PGypo1DZDgP3mTSsxhiCAlZzXE03pnEzVtYHqXzea0lO3kdqBbESHBH_HzcHin-j8KpsVAOqHLEuP1TAD1UOwfK3DfAPB5e8C0SVFLtzB=59BEgp-vvFpDKWYw9lXj9aB72Hg5PBBunlM1U-K1aKsJk-iyxMToh=EDK_ps7lyh36mLOeg_tbHi5vwrWiBvfmRSaibAC4bLjwMdNWVPh2LRido8L84vr7SNuwIB2fN22ZGw17tkj6KJTIBlqNK2d6Wk8_dEdPHAGholEdgPV0p7IEXdJseoK0q5sJNGhKECIxwIAlLp0JWmVgC1HPBWGDHljVWt3_nKYudJy6DHIHlew2huBtxy-xgEGwe8d=OwOXcez9nct0WjmY5Usqtid9JuFGp3nLtcW-Dpm6da6O=Cau2gt_bLo6A21=tod=HupF4bMgEPOAsG2YmAS7hS0=J-YMalGVVjdsS4_UVj6awBDgt1=TF5vGUZDjbZrDcb-v0ty3pqCOYTkGuEzUZRX6C2htE_5U3Fzu18Yk29XezGcsxbK=sd1XVK1sbK4HUZmPABAE4Em9GVM70SunOx8e=7doyu5KLnVibOwOyK=rOtbEpP=W6E=A9DDMB971_ABUy_LX2POg7Oufn7UU8R1PPDDgEBl=TNVxWIhFuLq_esXlaw3cBPXDpMFp_Cv1XVUvhFtmARcVZwFKfGOJT5o1TmefG4YOiO3Y9Hejdxsxxx8Hcrzxg0TkVy3E0lub4WU0b4gkw53BoeJOrqLemqHcwb06VfKi_Fq5a=T_RRtjfKROrGjHrRHn8RO74_mdFn_G3ScD5TeCcXxyZaEvbNBcawWSYN=_tdZBdzPGJPIGtM46yFTVR-VUS7ooONiVVjqvP7vffy-aeGuYrhPOSmfa3tw7ObwnYu6oU0bhKwjSlptpOw4F-6dvS4aUjJjp0qD6Xpjbw_oU7Vz0sH0r2h9iLEcNj-fTkyY6rHTtC4V-DXGukOpDw26AX-bHv5Kz0hpHZYh-6=DlOJG7jsIlAAILaBRp3x3IPdR2YGUjcA8bGjqWSuOyZ=PzxawCvvwj-ntBOa41kKtW6xlNevvLJCU_ArZNRxo--4PfT0b_YXazG0ReS3yXdKwxFgttuly

```json
     {
        "userTest": "" 
   }
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @Sheraff sorry i do not understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use create a JSON object, then use `JSON.stringify` convert it to a string you can write to a json file.

```js
const value = {
  "userText": "..."
};

fs.writeFile("path/to/output.json", JSON.stringify(value), (err) => console.log(err);
```

You can take a look at the JSON.stringify doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)